# Can't set Windows Product key from Powershell using variables

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to set the product key in powershell like this:

```
PS C:\> slmgr.vbs /ipk $var
```

But then I get Windows Script Host error 0xC004F050 — the product key is invalid.
I copy the key from the output of this command:

```
PS C:\> echo $var
XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

When I try to set it like this:

```
PS C:\> slmgr.vbs /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

Then the activation works.
What is the problem?

Comment: The simplest method would be to attempt to identify the value of the variable that is being used, using the PowerShell ISE, would be your best bet to determine that value.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use trim() function because the key contained one space at the end.